# Google API OAuth 2.0 Multiple Users in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, google-api

Have a really strange issue going on. Trying to implement Google's OAuth 2.0 in a ASP.NET (non-MVC) scenario to Google Calendar API. I see the token response in the storage area, no errors encountered.

Here's the code:

```
public CalendarService Credential(string sUserID)
{
    CalendarService service = new CalendarService();
    var folder = @"C:\TEMP\GoogleStorage";

    UserCredential credential = null;
    string clientId = "{client id is redacted}";
    string clientSecret = "{client secret is redacted}";
    string[] scopes = new string[] {CalendarService.Scope.Calendar};
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret
        },
        scopes,
        sUserID,
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(folder)
        ).Result;
    }
    service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Interpose Concept"
    });

    return service;
}
```

Here's the series of events:

1. I hit the above code and get a successful credential and a successful service returned. Google Account A using Chrome gets prompted to allow application to access the calendar. A token in stored at c:\temp\GoogleStorage
2. I am able to use the returned service to query User A's calendar.
3. Google Account B (simulating a different user hitting the same web server) using Firefox goes through the same code. A different UserID is passed into Credential based on this new session. Again, there's a successful credential to Google, this time userID is different, but this time no requiring to allow access to their Calendar. I am able to successfully return the service, but the service is for Google Account A's calendar.

I am certain I am missing something along the lines of being able to segregate the different Google Accounts, but I don't see how to separate the different users hitting this web server other than the user parameter in the AuthorAsync call I make. I further don't understand why it would retain the first account's credential.

What's blowing my mind is this *seems* to be working (first request is good, no errors, can query the calendar), but all subsequent requests seem to be tied to the first credential request that works.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Have you checked %appData% to see what FileDataStore is storing.  Just to be sure that it is actually storing two separate users.  It should if sUsierId is different.   I really wonder what FileDataStore will do with you passing it a directory.  I didn't think it supported that.